# Using authorize attribute ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use Authorize attribute to check if user is authorized or not to enter special view.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(int ID)
    {
             ViewBag.sID = ID;
             return View();
    }
```

Suppose this is mu URL : localhost:16621/Panel/Index/1 
Now this authorized user can change 1 to 2 and navigate to another user information. Like localhost:16621/Panel/Index/2
How to prevent from this??? Is there any way to pass parameter to authorize attribute?
How to prevent user from access another user information?

Comment: Angelina. this is so many time already asked on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329197/custom-form-authentication-authorization-scheme-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427598/customizing-authorization-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554094/asp-net-mvc-adding-to-the-authorize-attribute?rq=1

Comment: Look into this post, it does exactly what you want it to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064631/mvc-3-access-for-specific-user-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no magical switch - [Authorize] just kick off unauthorized users, users that are not within specified range, or users in wrong role. Safety of context-bound data is up to you - you'll have to do it within Index() body and redirect user elsewhere if the passed id is not available for actual user.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It's better to use a custom authorize attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "AuthenticationFilter" ASP.NET MVC5 available for exactly this purpose.

> [**Authentication filters**](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#TOC10)
>
> Authentication filters are a new kind of filter in ASP.NET MVC that
>   run prior to authorization filters in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline and
>   allow you to specify authentication logic per-action, per-controller,
>   or globally for all controllers. Authentication filters process
>   credentials in the request and provide a corresponding principal.
>   Authentication filters can also add authentication challenges in
>   response to unauthorized requests.

See [this tutorial](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/28/asp_net-authentication-filters.aspx) for how to use it.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Filters;

namespace VSMMvc5AuthFilterDemo.CustomAttributes
{
  public class BasicAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
  {
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
      var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
      if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
      }
    }
  }
}
```