# IIS Authorization MVC Controller full URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm new to stackoverflow so please bear with me. I haven't found a direct answer to my question.

I am using an MVC web application developed by a third party. There is a particular controller for which I would like to secure viewing of one the items to certain users.
So, for example, the URL a user may hit is:
.../#/MyViews/1

Generally that is fine for all (Windows) authenticated users to see all the MyViews items. However, there may be a few that I would only like one or two users/groups to be able to view. The third party may support that functionality in the future but they don't right now.
I was hoping that IIS authorization would help me out by altering the web.config but I can't get it to work.

I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
<location path="#/MyViews/234">
   <allow users="domain\username" />
</location>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It may just be that I can't do it, but I hate having to wait for the third party to provide the functionality.

Am I misunderstanding the capability of the "location" functionality?

Any other potential options to resolve this?

Comment: You can user custom Authorize attribute on Actions that your want to be accessed. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10069844/1081079

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I don't have the source code to modify/extend, this is a 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `web.config` [location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx) settings are meant exclusively for file-based authentication. The values that you put there correspond to physical directories and files on the web server, not to URLs.

MVC does not serve files, it serves resources from controller action methods programmatically. Therefore the web server (via `web.config`) has no way to override its security. The [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is the only sure way to secure an MVC application because it involves locking down the resource (controller action) rather than securing by URL, which would fail if there is an alternate route that can access the same controller action.

The only option you have if you don't have the source code and have no way to plug in your own code is to hope that the 3rd party put some option into the software to configure the security to the level that you need, which would probably involve a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) subclass that has some settings that can be configured in a configuration file or through a control panel.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was beginning to suspect during my testing. I guess I was still hoping that there was a way to do it before the URL was handed off to the application.
I could technically modify the view models and inject some javascript to perform a URL authorisation check, which is what I will likely try next.